# Multiprocessing lock working differently when initialized as global/local variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, locking, python-multiprocessing

I am using multiprocessing locks to make file access multiprocessing safe. I'm getting unexpected behavior depending on where I instantiate my lock.

In the code below, I have option 1 and option 2. Depending on which option I end up using I get different results. Option 1 produces the expected results where the lock blocks other processes from doing work until the process with the lock releases it. Option 2 on the other hand will behave as if the lock doesn't exist, almost like the locks between the processes are not shared. Below is also the results of both runs. I even print the ID's but they are different values among the processes so I couldn't derive any information from that. Why does option 1 work as expected but option 2 doesn't?

I'm using python 3.7.3

```
# file1.py
from file2 import ProcessManager

class Program:
    def __init__(self):
        self.manager = ProcessManager()
    def start(self):
        self.manager.run()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    program = Program()
    program.start()

# file2.py
import multiprocessing
from file3 import workingProcess

PACKAGE_LOCK = multiprocessing.Lock() # Option 1: Worked as expected

class ProcessManager:
    def __init__(self):

        self.proc = [] # list of processes

    def run(self):
    
        # package_lock = multiprocessing.Lock() Option 2: Would not work as expected
        
        for i in range(3):
            self.proc.append(
                multiprocessing.Process(
                    target=workingProcess,
                    name=f"Process {i}",
                    args=(i, PACKAGE_LOCK,) # Option 1: Worked as expected
                    # args=(i, package_lock,) # Option 2: Would not work as expected
                )
            self.proc[-1].start()

        # Do other stuff

# file3.py  
def workingProcess(
    process_idx,
    package_lock
):
    package_lock.acquire()
    print(f"{process_idx} start {time.time()}")
    print(f"{process_idx} ID {id(package_lock)}")
    # Do Stuff
    print(f"{process_idx} finished {time.time()}")
    package_lock.release()
```

Option 1 results

```
0 start 1633029033.4513052
0 ID 3096670642920
0 finished 1633029047.2527368
1 start 1633029047.2537322
1 ID 2665907335800
```

Option 2 results:

```
0 start 1633028808.6572444
0 ID 1627297871128
1 start 1633028810.7597322
1 ID 2176530584688
2 start 1633028813.3802645
2 ID 2811978711784
0 finished 1633028823.7506292
```

Comment: You are creating a `Lock` instance in both case **but in neither case do you ever use it** (as in calling `acquire` and `release`). **There is no code even to `start` the processes you have created.** See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, please tag your question with the platform you are running on according to the SO guidelines.

Comment: @Booboo sorry I didn't copy a part of the code. Fixed.

Comment: Can you add the code which instantiates `ProcessManager` and calls `run()`?

Comment: @quamrana Added where the `run()` is called and also how the 3 components are separated by python scripts.

Comment: Not sure why you are running subprocess as `daemon`, because once you finished creating them, main process will exit, and terminate all child processes, I suppose that's clearly NOT what you wanted, so don't understand your output you posted..
Both Locks are working as expected under python 3.8 for me

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is still not quite a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example); it is missing required import statements, has multiple syntax errors such as a missing closing `)`, inconsistent use of `multiprocessing` and `mp`, `testsuite` is not defined, etc.

I have attempted to clean up the code so your "option 2" compiles and runs and I see no problem (I have moved the class definitions to the beginning of the source):

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

class ProcessManager:
    def __init__(self):

        self.proc = [] # list of processes

    def run(self):

        package_lock = mp.Lock()

        for i in range(3):
            self.proc.append(
                mp.Process(
                    target=workingProcess,
                    name=f"Process {i}",
                    args=(i, package_lock,) # Option 2: Would not work as expected
                )
            )
            self.proc[-1].start()

def workingProcess(
    process_idx,
    package_lock
):
    package_lock.acquire()
    print(f"{process_idx} start {time.time()}")
    print(f"{process_idx} ID {id(package_lock)}")
    # Do Stuff
    print(f"{process_idx} finished {time.time()}")
    package_lock.release()

class Program:
    def __init__(self):
        self.manager = ProcessManager()
    def start(self):
        self.manager.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    program = Program()
    program.start()
```

Prints:

```
0 start 1633092270.5815103
0 ID 2430872331648
0 finished 1633092270.5845103
1 start 1633092270.5845103
1 ID 1643658290560
1 finished 1633092270.586511
2 start 1633092270.586511
2 ID 2922265716096
2 finished 1633092270.5885122
```